# PHP Modal Displays Correct jpg from 'img src=' BUT javascript code to print ALWAYS displays and prints last image file in folder?

Tags: php, printing, modal-dialog, glob

1. Have folder of 86 jpg images
2. Have PHP page glob to retrieve all file names
3. Have table displaying small image, file name, size, and 'view' button
4. 'View' button opens modal displaying the correct/corresponding image and file name with 'print' button

## All above functions work - click button, get modal with correct image

## The below function does not work correctly

5. The modal's HTML code opens to the LAST file in folder by name (alpha) file = 99978_211410.jpg although I'm using the same variables used to list the images in the table and display the image in the modal (which) works. When using the variable in the modal's html I'm getting the last image in the file's folder.
   If I remove the last file I get the same result with the current last file listed in the folder.

Code Notes:
$filename is the actual file name  / basename($file)
$sketchImage is the folder location and name / (/tempSketches/.$filename)
These 2 variables work in in the table and modal always displaying the correct image. Only the creation of the HTML (print page) do I get the last file in the folder

printWindow.document.write is creating the HTML page to print (have to scroll below to view)
[image]

```js
<script>
    function printModal() {
        var printableContent = document.getElementById('printableContent').innerHTML;
        var printWindow = window.open('_blank');
        printWindow.document.open();
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Vision+ Sketch: "<?php echo $filename;?>"</title></head><body><center><h5 class="modal-title text-primary font-weight-bolder" style="font-size:44px" id="printSketchFileName">PROPERTY APPRAISER<br>VISION+ SKETCH MANAGER<br>SKETCH FILE: "<?php echo $filename;?>"</h5><img src="<?php echo $sketchImage;?>" style=width:1400px; height 1400px></center></body></html > ');
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.print();
    }
</script>
```

```html
<?php
require_once './includes/favicon.php';
require_once 'ske_view_index.php';
?>
<!-- ||||||||||||||||||||||||| SKETCH VIEW ||||||||||||||||||||||||| -->
<!-- /\/\/\/\ -->
<!-- SKETCH: VIEW Modal -->
<!-- \/\/\/\/ -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ske_modal_view_<?php echo $filename?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content" style="border-radius: 25px">
            <div id="printableContent">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title text-primary font-weight-bolder" id="ModalLabel"> SKETCH MANAGER | SKETCH VIEWER</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body bg-primary">
                    <form method="POST" action ="emp_action_add.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <br>
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $sketchImage?>"  id="<?php $sketchImage?>">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <p class="text-center text-light text-uppercase font-weight-bolder" style="font-size: 24px"><?php echo 'SKETCH FILE: '.$filename?></p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-bs-dismiss="modal"> CLOSE </button>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="PRINT SKETCH" onclick="printModal()"> PRINT </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to pass the correct Filename to printModal() function. Image src is $sketchImage without any index so this value is always the last file of the loop you have in php code for listing the files of directory. For fixing the issue you need to retrieve the correct filename and sketch image inside the function with something like printModal(fileName, sketchImage) and then use this values inside the function for image and file src. You can pass this two values with the button that call the function